# localhost redirected you too many times.ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a login and registration auth plugin which is OTP based , here is the code :

```
function my_redirect_handle_fun()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $is_admin = current_user_can('administrator');
        $verified = get_user_meta($user_id, "verified", true);



        if (!$is_admin) {
            if (!$verified) {
                error_log("Redirecting to OTP page.");
                wp_redirect(site_url("otp"));
                exit();
            }
        }

    }

    
}
```

I just want to redirect the user to the otp page after registration process .
**$verified** = it is nothing but a verified status stored in the meta data of user to check wheather user validated the otp or not.

**$is_admin** = I dont want to redirect the admin to the otp page thats why I explicitly mention the case to handle that situation.

All the Logic for validating otp is written in the otp page section.

but problem is that the above code is not giving the expected output, it just showing that **localhost redirected you too many times** , after reloading for a long period

Comment: it's pretty self explanatory, it's in a redirect loop, ie. page A redirects to page B which redirects to page A and so on ... make sure that the code used to decide if a redirection is needed or not is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when `php` hits this line

```php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
```

It's seeing that the user `is` logged in and still redirecting them.

I think you meant if the user is **not** (!) logged in,

```php
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
```

then redirect them.